# Particle density and current in terms of Green function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, fermions, propagator

Consider a non-relativistic free-fermion system. I am wondering how to calculate observables like average particle density and average current in terms of momentum-space Green functions. I know that the real-space relationships are:

$$\langle\rho(r,t)\rangle = -i\lim_{r'\rightarrow r}\lim_{t'\rightarrow t^-} G_F(r,t; r',t') $$
and
$$\langle j(r,t)\rangle = -\frac{1}{2m}\lim_{r'\rightarrow r}\lim_{t'\rightarrow t^-} \left(\nabla_r^i - \nabla_{r'}^i \right) G_F(r,t; r',t') $$

However, if I directly Fourier transform the density, for example, I find
$$\sum_q e^{iqr}\langle \rho(q,t) \rangle= -i\lim_{r'\rightarrow r}\lim_{t'\rightarrow t^-} \sum_{k,k'} e^{-ikr} e^{ik'r'} \langle \psi^\dagger(k,t) \psi(k',t') \rangle = -i \sum_{k,k'} e^{-i(k-k')r}\langle \psi^\dagger(k,t) \psi(k',t) \rangle$$

By identifying $q = k'-k$, it appears that the expectation value of the density is
$$ \langle \rho(q,t) \rangle= -i \sum_k\langle \psi^\dagger(k,t) \psi(k+q,t) \rangle$$

However, this expression does not seem easily expressible in terms of momentum-space Green functions, which look like
$$ G_0(k,t) = \langle \psi^\dagger(k,t)\psi(k,t) \rangle$$
Similarly, the momentum-space representation of the current appears to be
$$\langle j(r,t)\rangle = -\frac{1}{2m} \sum_k (2k+q) \langle \psi^\dagger(k,t)\psi(k+q,t)\rangle$$
Is it possible to rewrite these in terms of the momentum-space Green functions?

Comment: Your first equation is similar to eq.(31.5) in Landau-Lifshitz Vol 9. Then I guess (31.6) there is what you want.